# Помогите решить проблему не могу разобрать интерфейс

Tags: golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/beldur/kraken-go-api-client"
    "config"
)

func main() {
    api := krakenapi.New(config.API_KEY, config.PRIVAT_KEY)
    result, err := api.Query("Depth", map[string]string{
        "pair": "XXBTZUSD",
        "count": "10",
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Result : %v \nType : %t",result, result)


}
```

Выывод в консоль

```
Result : map[XXBTZUSD:map[asks:[[2663.14800 0.403 1.497978279e+09] [2664.48000 1.000 1.497978282e+09] [2664.48100 0.735 1.497978282e+09] [2665.99000 1.000 1.497978242e+09] [2666.00000 0.717 1.497978227e+09] [2666.26300 3.440 1.497978276e+09] [2666.31400 0.890 1.49797803e+09] [2666.66000 2.000 1.497972848e+09] [2667.00100 1.100 1.497771542e+09] [2668.99400 14.286 1.497978263e+09]] bids:[[2653.10100 0.910 1.497978279e+09] [2653.08700 0.461 1.497978268e+09] [2653.06100 0.369 1.49797826e+09] [2653.03000 7.660 1.497978274e+09] [2653.02100 5.540 1.497978221e+09] [2653.00000 18.100 1.497978189e+09] [2652.91300 0.010 1.497978204e+09] [2651.68300 4.000 1.497977846e+09] [2650.85400 0.010 1.497978023e+09] [2650.00100 1.000 1.497978266e+09]]]] 

Type : map[%!t(string=XXBTZUSD):map[%!t(string=asks):[[%!t(string=2663.14800) %!t(string=0.403) %!t(float64=1.497978279e+09)] [%!t(string=2664.48000) %!t(string=1.000) %!t(float64=1.497978282e+09)] [%!t(string=2664.48100) %!t(string=0.735) %!t(float64=1.497978282e+09)] [%!t(string=2665.99000) %!t(string=1.000) %!t(float64=1.497978242e+09)] [%!t(string=2666.00000) %!t(string=0.717) %!t(float64=1.497978227e+09)] [%!t(string=2666.26300) %!t(string=3.440) %!t(float64=1.497978276e+09)] [%!t(string=2666.31400) %!t(string=0.890) %!t(float64=1.49797803e+09)] [%!t(string=2666.66000) %!t(string=2.000) %!t(float64=1.497972848e+09)] [%!t(string=2667.00100) %!t(string=1.100) %!t(float64=1.497771542e+09)] [%!t(string=2668.99400) %!t(string=14.286) %!t(float64=1.497978263e+09)]] %!t(string=bids):[[%!t(string=2653.10100) %!t(string=0.910) %!t(float64=1.497978279e+09)] [%!t(string=2653.08700) %!t(string=0.461) %!t(float64=1.497978268e+09)] [%!t(string=2653.06100) %!t(string=0.369) %!t(float64=1.49797826e+09)] [%!t(string=2653.03000) %!t(string=7.660) %!t(float64=1.497978274e+09)] [%!t(string=2653.02100) %!t(string=5.540) %!t(float64=1.497978221e+09)] [%!t(string=2653.00000) %!t(string=18.100) %!t(float64=1.497978189e+09)] [%!t(string=2652.91300) %!t(string=0.010) %!t(float64=1.497978204e+09)] [%!t(string=2651.68300) %!t(string=4.000) %!t(float64=1.497977846e+09)] [%!t(string=2650.85400) %!t(string=0.010) %!t(float64=1.497978023e+09)] [%!t(string=2650.00100) %!t(string=1.000) %!t(float64=1.497978266e+09)]]]]
```

Как мне с этими данными работать , поскольку `fmt.println(result[""])`
Ругается `invalid operation: result[""] (type interface {} does not support indexing)`

Проболвал ручками

```
a :=  result.(map[string]interface{})
for k, v := range a{
    fmt.Println(k)
    for key, value := range v.(map[string]interface{}){
        fmt.Println("   ", key)
        for o, b := range value.([]interface{}){
            fmt.Println("       ", o, b)
        }
    }
}
```

Но всеравно не доконца пошло дело. 
Помогите решить проблему .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Авторы библиотеки не создали специальный тип для ответа запроса.
У тебя есть два выбора:

1. Использовать [сравнение типов (type assertion)](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15)

https://play.golang.org/p/tCQgQDBBqQ

2. Парсить тело ответа в собственную структуру. Надо знать [как парсить json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)

https://play.golang.org/p/y1qGydSjvI

Я советую второй вариант. Но сравнение типов тоже обязательно для изучения.